# How can I remove words from a list that start with one of the letters in another list?

Tags: python, list

Complete beginner here. I am trying to remove words from a list that start with one of the letters in another list.

So if

```
list_of_words = ['apple', 'apricot', 'banana', 'blueberry', 'cherry']

list_of_letters = ['a', 'c']
```

Then I'd like my final list to be

```
['banana', 'blueberry']
```

In case it's relevant, my actual lists are a lot longer than these two examples.

What should I do?

**Thank you!**

---

Edit:

Yes, I did try to code it, but I didn't include it in the initial post since I was sure it was completely off-base.

But what I tried was

```
def first_letter_program(first_letter, word_list):
    if first_letter == word_list[0]:
        return new_word_list.remove(word_list)

first_letter_program(list_of_letters, word_list)
```

Maybe I should've included it in the first place to show that I did at least put some effort into this.

Comment: ``"What should I do?"`` - start writing some code. If you're not sure how to start, start by reading [tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have some piece of code at least?

Comment: Could you add the `qualified` words into a new list?  Or If the requirement does not allow you to modify the orig. list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
result = []
for word in list_of_words:
    if word[0] not in list_of_letters: 
        result.append(word)
```

Or functional way:

```
def first_letter_program(first_letter, word_list):
    result = []
    for word in word_list:  # looping each word in the word_list
       if word[0] not in first_letter:  # check the first letter of each word 
          result.append(word)
    return result

>>>
```